# Strategy Design Pattern - How many algorithms are too many?

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, logic, strategy-pattern

I'm about to implement the strategy design pattern into my project to handle all the different behaviors based on the user's role. For a simple example, I have a method to fetch all the orders in the system, like `getOrders()`.

There are about 8 different roles in the system, and most of them are handled differently. For instance, some users are only allowed to see certain orders. Some can see all, or some can see only the ones that belong to them. Before, I used to use one method in a "service class" and would conditionally check there. The example is just one method, but it really happens throughout the system for data retrieval. So I thought it would be cleaner if I extracted those conditional methods into a separate class, which can be switched out depending on their role. So each class would have that `getOrders()` method, and I can define it for each role.

Now, does that sound like a feasible way to do this? Is there a general upper limit of classes I should be aware of, before deciding that there might be a better way to handle this?

I also thought about combining the `decorator` pattern as well. Not to go on a tangent, but I believe this would allow me to let manager roles to get everything their subordinates have, by decorating what they already have implemented, and then adding on if needed.

On a side note, I'm using Laravel and was going to switch out the classes by binding the concrete implementation in the `AppServiceProvider`.

Any input would be great, thanks!

Comment: 8 could be too many or just right -- all depends. The point of using software patterns is to make code easier to maintain and extend. If the pattern meets that goal with 88 strategy classes -- great. If it feels unwieldy and awkward with 8 -- revisit the design. There is no "upper limit".

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, that makes sense. I know the saying of "it depends." To me, it seems right. And we actually have 12 roles. But still, if it doesn't seem absurd in a general sense, then that's just the kind of confirmation I was looking for.